# view with 4 tables left join group by

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables:

```
**Subscribers**
SubscriberId
SubscriberName
DateCreated

**SubscriberVotes**
SubscriberID
QuestionID
Points
DateCreated

**Store**
ItemID
ItemPoints

**SusbscriberStoreActivity**
SubscriberID
ItemID
DateCreated
```

I need to create a view that will contain :

`SubscriberID`

`total point from subscribervotes`

`total point from subscriberstoreactivity`

This is what I have so far:

```
Select 
  s.SubscriberID , 
  ssa.PointsWasted
From 
  subscribers s
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      sum(se.Points) AS PointsWasted , 
      g.SubscriberID as SubscriberID
    From 
      SubscriberStoreActivity g 
    LEFT JOIN STORE se 
      on g.ItemID=se.ItemID
    GROUP BY  g.SubscriberID
  )  ssa on ssa.SubscriberID= s.SubscriberID 
GROUP BY s.subscriberID
```

but i keep getting error in my sql cant have subquery...

** edit **

```
sample data
**subscribers**
subscriber id      subscriber name
1                   david
2                   james

**subscriber votes**
subscriberid      voteid     points
1                   5          50
1                   3          15
2                   4          75 

**store**
item id           points
1                    10
2                    4
3                    20

subscriberstoreactivity

subscriberid   itemid
  1               1
  1               1
  1               2
  2               3
```

Comment: What part are you having a problem with? Show us your code so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
    sub.SubscriberID,
    sum(sv.Points) as SubscriberPoints,
    sum(st.ItemPoints) as StorePoints
from
    Subscriber sub
    left join SubscriberVotes sv on
        sub.SubscriberID = sv.SubscriberID
    left join SubscriberStoreActivity ssa on
        sub.SubscriberID = ssa.SubscriberID
    left join Store st on
        ssa.ItemID = st.ItemID
group by
    sub.SubscriberID
```

There's no reason to do a subquery here--you can do exactly what you want in one query, so just do it once and don't worry about it.

Comment: I don't know what the right results are. Can you provide some sample data? The query will give you the total points from `SubscriberStore` table associated with the `SubscriberID`, and the total points from the `Store` table with any `ItemID` that's tied to the given `SubscriberID`.

Comment: i edited my question
from your query i get : subscriber 1  195 48. subscriber 2  20 20. but the right result should be subscriber1 65 24 . subscriber 2 20 20